# dynamic query returning parameter giving hard time

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @Count INT

SET @SQL = 'SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE lastname = ''alex'''

print @sql
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Count int OUTPUT'
SELECT @Count
```

When I run it, I get following error. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

> Msg 8178, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The parameterized query '(@Count int OUTPUT)SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM customers WHERE ' expects the parameter '@Count', which was not supplied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to supply `@Count` parameter as a part of `sp_executesql` call (note that in this case it should be marked `OUTPUT` as well):

```
...

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Count int OUTPUT', @Count OUTPUT
SELECT @Count
```

The second pararmeter in the `sp_executesql` call is the query parameters definition, or so called *formal parameters* (in your case there is single parameter `N'@Count int OUTPUT'`). If query is parameterized, then what should go after (the third and subsequent parameters) are so called *actual parameters*.

Below samples may explain better:

```
-- sample query #1
-- will fail, because of query is pararmeterized,
-- and actual pararmeter is not provided
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @Num', N'@Num int';

-- sample query #2
-- formal parameter is @Num of type int
-- actual parameter is literal constant 153
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @Num', N'@Num int', 153;

-- sample query #3
-- formal parameter is @Num of type int
-- actual parameter is variable @p
DECLARE @p int;
SET @p = 1;
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @Num', N'@Num int', @p;

-- sample query #4
DECLARE @p int;
SET @p = 15;
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @Num=@Num*2', N'@Num int output', @p output
select @p;
```